# service based database

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mdf

I have one problem with service base database, I have used it in one of my application but I dont know if user who'll use it need to have something installed to be able to run application (like you need to have installed NET framework for c# applications)

Note: This is **windows** application

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what database engine you're using. SQL Server/SQL Express/Oracle/MySQL require you install the application on the machine before it'll work. databases engines like SQLite and Firebird are just Dll's, so you can include then in your project.

If the file is an MDF that's a SQL Server file - you need to install SQL server, or SQL express.

You can include it with your app and do it silently:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/7180e4dc-5c1e-4501-83d7-6882abb1f04e/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the relevant database engine with the correct service name, and create the database and relevant objects on installation.